# ajax sql php in xml format ,ie error

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have ajax code ,sql retrived using php code in xml format.I want to display xml using ajax request javascript code when the page loading .
I have got this working on firefox,chrome, however on internet explorer gives this error:

*SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference*

THIS error in line 2 of below function:

```
REQ.getRequest("getXML.php" , displayXMLOnl, true);
function displayXMLOnl( data ){
    var root = data.documentElement; // the error in this line
    }
```

Comment: What kind of object is `REQ` and how does it handle the callback function `displayXMLOnl()`? It sounds/looks like it isn't passing the return-data in IE (based on the info you've given).

Comment: REQ.getRequest is just a function in my ajax code

Comment: var REQ = REQ || {};
REQ.getRequest = function ( url, callbackFunction, useXML ) {
 var httpRequest;

Comment: the IE debugger indicates that data is null,

Comment: however HTML format displayed fine on IE ,just XML not